# Javascript scroll​Into​View() method does not work for the first time in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, js-scrollintoview

I'm trying to scroll to a DOM element after new DOM element renders on a button click, in a react app. But the scroll does not work for the first time.

The scroll has to happen after a state variable changes. I've, thus, put the code in a callback.

```
this.setState({ showChart: true }, ()=> {

    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.chart).scrollIntoView({ 
    behavior: "smooth", block: "end" });
 });
```

Comment: where in your code are you calling this `setState`?

Comment: on a button click

Comment: I mean, where in  the DOM? If you can post the component code or related would be helpful.